# How to delete a database in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

I've tried `db.delete()`, I've tried `db.deleteOne()` they all return an error. I now you use `show dbs` to show all databases but i need the command to delete a database. This is what i tried in my shell:[image]

Comment: Use drop() for delete db

Comment: I ended up using dropDatabase() but thanks